# Remove logo from cover page in IReports RMarkdown Template

Tags: r

I am using the `ireports` RMarkdown Template to create a PDF (see https://www.inwt-statistics.com/read-blog/r-markdown-template-for-business-reports.html). Just wondering whether there is a way to remove the logo at the bottom right corner of the cover page without removing it from the header of every page subsequent to that?

Comment: Did you try setting these `params` to nothing (`NULL`)? `logo: logo.png
  cover: cover.png` See the source [code](https://github.com/INWTlab/ireports/blob/2bdeedba351bdbd5127b928df13bf2d69e57b1ae/inst/rmarkdown/templates/business_report/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd). Can't test.

Comment: @NelsonGon If I set ```logo: logo.png``` to ```NULL```, it will remove the logo from both the cover page as well as in the header of each page. I only want it removed from the cover page (and for it to remain on each header after the cover page)